# AAD microsoft graph, client credentials

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I have setup an Office 365 E3 trial account. I registered two apps in AAD.

The first one uses the "authorization code flow" and does work as expected (can access the logged in users calendar).

The second app uses the "client credentials flow" and does not work.

1. login in Browser (Edge)

   ```
   GET /OAuthTest3 HTTP/1.1

   HTTP/1.1 302 Found
   Location: https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant>/adminconsent?client_id=<app_id>&redirect_uri=http://localhost:1234/OAuthTest3

   GET /OAuthTest3?admin_consent=True&tenant=<tenant> HTTP/1.1

   HTTP/1.1 200 OK
   ```
2. connect to https://login.microsoftonline.com/

   ```
   POST /<tenant>/oauth2/token HTTP/1.1
   Host: login.microsoftonline.com

   client_id=<app_id>&
   client_secret=<client_secret>&
   grant_type=client_credentials&
   redirect_uri=http://localhost:1234/OAuthTest3&
   resource=https://graph.microsoft.com/&
   scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/calendars.readwrite


   HTTP/1.1 200 OK
   {
     "token_type": "Bearer",
     "expires_in": "3600",
     "ext_expires_in": "0",
     "expires_on": "1504333342",
     "not_before": "1504329442",
     "resource": "https://graph.microsoft.com/",
     "access_token": <token>
   }
   ```
3. connect to https://graph.microsoft.com/

   ```
   GET /v1.0/users/<user>/calendars HTTP/1.1
   Host: graph.microsoft.com
   Authorization: Bearer <token>

   HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
   {
       "error": {
       "code": "ErrorAccessDenied",
       "message": "Access is denied. Check credentials and try again.",
           "innerError": {
               "request-id": "e7228de4-2b27-4779-abef-ccab0d88970a",
               "date": "2017-09-02T05:22:27"
           }
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Hello Emil. I suppose you are using the V2 endpoint, also which library are you using?

Comment: Hi Jean-Marc, I use the endpoints https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant>/adminconsent and https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant>/oauth2/token for authorization.
And https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/<user-id> for the graph api. I am implementing my own libraries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to use Client Credentials flow in AAD V2.0, you need to first object Admin Consent for your application. This is true even if you wouldn't need consent for the same scope using Authorization Code grant.

Take a look at [v2 Endpoint and Admin Consent](http://massivescale.com/microsoft-v2-endpoint-admin-consent/) for a walk-through on obtaining consent.

UPDATE:

Scopes work differently with Client Credentials. Rather than dynamically requesting the scopes using a space delimited list (`https://graph.microsoft.com/user.read https://graph.microsoft.com/calendars.readwrite`), you need to define them in your app's registration.

This is done using the https://apps.dev.microsoft.com portal. In your app's registration, find the "Application Permissions" section and click the "Add" button. This will pop a dialog where you can select the permissions you need:

[image: permissions]

In your application, you also need to change your `scope` parameter so the system knows to use the scopes from your registration. This is done by passing `https://graph.microsoft.com/.default` for the scope:

```
POST /<tenant>/oauth2/v2.0/token HTTP/1.1
Host: login.microsoftonline.com

client_id=<app_id>&
client_secret=<client_secret>&
grant_type=client_credentials&
redirect_uri=http://localhost:1234/OAuthTest3&
resource=https://graph.microsoft.com/&
scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
```

**Important:** Any time you make a change to your scopes, you will have to re-execute the Admin Consent flow before those new scopes will consented.